# My C code does not work but another example, something similar to me, works. Why?

Tags: c, pointers, pthread-join

My code is not working... But another example that is similar to my code is working. How can I fix?

It seems like `pthread_join()` is internally change integer value like my code. But mine does not work.

Can anybody help me to fix?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(void **temp) {
    int foo = 3;
    *temp = foo;
}

int main(void) {
    int temp;

    test((void **)&temp);
    printf("%d\n", temp);

    return 0;
}
```

`pthread_join` example:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *test(void *data) {
    int i;
    int a = *(int *)data;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i * a);
    }
}

int main() {
    int a = 100;
    pthread_t thread_t;
    int status;

    if (pthread_create(&thread_t, NULL, test, (void *)&a) < 0) {
        perror("thread create error:");
        exit(0);
    }

    pthread_join(thread_t, (void **)&status);
    printf("Thread End %d\n", status);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You have a double pointer (`void**`), and the example you're referencing has only single pointers (`void*`).  That matters.

Answer (score 1):

> But mine does not work..

This statement:

```
pthread_join(thread_t, (void **)&status);
```

assigns to status the *return* value of your thread function. But your function doesn't return *anything*, so you get garbage.

To fix this, make your `test` function return something.

P.S. Please do turn on compiler warnings (`-Wall`, `-Wextra`) -- the compiler should have warned you of the bug already.

P.P.S Please do not name your variables like this: `thread_t` -- the `_t` stands for *type*, and `thead_t` is *not* a type.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make temp into two void pointers (void**) when you actually only have one pointer to the int temp. Just return the pointer value and you can use this in a similar pthread example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *test(void *temp) {
    int *ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ptr = 3;
    return ptr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *temp = (int*)test(nullptr);
    printf("%d\n", *temp);
    free(temp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I actually want to make my own pthread_join function. So, I must not to change parameter type.. How can I do it with void ** type?

Comment: The test function in the pthread_join example just takes type void*. I changed the example to show this.